# Getting 'Block "my-plugin/block-name" is already registered' in Gutenberg editor

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to create a plugin that will have multiple blocks and an admin page. Everything seems to be working fine. The admin page is showing up, the blocks are working as well. But I am getting an error in the console when I get to the Gutenberg editor and that is making me worried if what I did is wrong or not.

This is the error:

`'Block "my-plugin/block-1" is already registered'`
`'Block "my-plugin/block-2" is already registered'`

This is the plugin php file:

```
class MY_PLUGIN{
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'menu_item' ] );
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'load_custom_wp_admin_scripts' ] );
        add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'register_blocks' ] );
    }

    /**
    * Initialize the plugin
    */
    public static function init(){
        static $instance = false; 
        if( !$instance ) {
            $instance = new self();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
    * Create a new admin page for our app.
    */
    public function menu_item() {
        add_menu_page(
            'My Plugin',
            'My Plugin',
            'manage_options',
            'my-plugin',
            [ $this, 'dashboard_page' ],
            'dashicons-schedule',
            3
        );
    }

    /**
    * Admin page markup.
    */
    public function dashboard_page() {
        echo '
            <h2>Pages</h2>
            <div id="my-plugin"></div>
        ';
    }

    /**
    * Load admin scripts and stylesheets
    */
    public function load_custom_wp_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
        // Load only on ?page=my-plugin
        if ( 'toplevel_page_my-plugin' !== $hook ) {
            return;
        }

        // Load the required WordPress packages.

        // Automatically load imported dependencies and assets version.
        $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php';

        // Enqueue CSS dependencies.
        foreach ( $asset_file['dependencies'] as $style ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( $style );
        }

        // Load our app.js.
        wp_register_script(
            'my-plugin',
            plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
            $asset_file['dependencies'],
            $asset_file['version']
        );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin' );

        // Load our style.css.
        wp_register_style(
            'my-plugin',
            plugins_url( 'src/admin/stylesheet/style.css', __FILE__ ),
            array(),
            $asset_file['version']
        );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
    }

    public function register_blocks() {
        register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/block-1' );
        register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/block-2' );
   }
}
```

Each block's index.js file looks like this:

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';
import Edit from './edit';
import Save from './save';
import metadata from './block.json';

/**
 * Every block starts by registering a new block type definition.
*/
registerBlockType( metadata, {
    edit: Edit,
    save: Save,
} );
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

*****UPDATE******
Here's how block.json looks like. Both block's the same except name and title is different in each. Like block-1 and block-2:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "my-plugin/block-1",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Block 1",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "flag",
    "description": "Some description",
    "attributes": {
        "message": {
            "type": "string",
            "source": "text",
            "selector": "div"
        }
    },
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "block-1",
    "editorScript": "file:../../index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:../../index.css",
    "style": "file:../../style-index.css"
}
```

FOLDER STRUCTURE:

[image]

Admin Index.js:

```
import { render }                   from '@wordpress/element';
import App                          from './components/App/App';

window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function () {
        render(
            <App />,
            document.querySelector( '#my-plugin' )
        );
    },
    false
);
```

UPDATE:

Getting these errors in admin side and blocks are missing after adding custom webpack file as suggested by S.Walsh.

[image]

UPDATE:

After implementing S.Walsh's suggestions, the blocks were working fine but admin page was not showing any components. So I updated `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts` function to build path for the register script:

```
public function load_custom_wp_admin_scripts($hook) {
    if ('toplevel_page_my-plugin' !== $hook) {
        return;
    }

    $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) .'build/admin/index.asset.php';

    foreach ( $asset_file['dependencies'] as $style ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( $style );
    }

    wp_register_script('my-plugin', plugins_url('build/admin/index.js', __FILE__), $asset_file['dependencies'], $asset_file['version']);
    wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin');

    wp_register_style('my-plugin', plugins_url('src/admin/stylesheet/style.css', __FILE__), array(), $asset_file['version']);
    wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin');
}
```

The components are showing up now but the stylesheet in not taking any effect.

UPDATE:

For the admin styles to take effect, the css file should be changed to scss. And also update it in `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts` function. I also removed view.js files as it is not needed.

Comment: Might want to include the contents of `block.json` as well so others can help.

Comment: @cabrerahector Updated the post with block.json content.

Comment: You're registering your block twice, using PHP and javascript, you should register using javascript and remove your register method and also remove add_action for the same method in __construct method. Thanks

Comment: @nikhil I tried that before after removing `register_block_type` from php file. The blocks disappear after doing that.

Comment: What does `my-plugin/src/blocks/index.js` contain? Does it call `registerBlockType` for each block too? This could explain the duplicate registration warning when PHP `wp_register_script('my-plugin',plugins_url('build/index.js', __FILE__ )...)` is called, as they are being registered in PHP again via `public function register_blocks(){...}`

Comment: @S.Walsh `my-plugin/src/blocks` dir does not have an index.js file. I have an index.js file in `src` dir which contains the import of the admin's index.js and both the block's index.js. I have posted the folder structure in the post. Please check it.

Comment: Can you try console.log next to the block declaration? To see how many times it runs?

Comment: @Mtxz did you mean in block's index.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is triggered in **plugin.php** by the function `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts()` as:

1. The file `src/index.js` contains code to register the blocks on the [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/) hooks in `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts()`.
2. The blocks are also registered via the `register_blocks()` function using each blocks `block.json` on the [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook.

When you visit your custom Admin page, the `admin_enqueue_scripts` and `init` hook both attempt to register the blocks, creating the error.

Your screenshot shows that the script entry point is compiling all the assets into `index.asset.php` hence your blocks build directories only contains the `block.json` files without their assets.

The best practise is to keep the block code independent of any other plugin JavaScript, for this kind of project setup, you can define multiple entry points to build the required assets.

**Solution**

Let's set up a basic plugin project with multiple blocks from the start to explore an alternative approach:

**1. Project Setup**
*via command line with [@wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/):*

```bash
# 1. Create "my-plugin" and install required files
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest my-plugin

# 2. Remove the default src directory that contains the default single block
rmdir /s my-plugin\src

# 3. Make a new src\blocks directory and enter it
mkdir my-plugin\src\blocks && cd my-plugin\src\blocks

# 4. Use create block to scaffold new blocks as required with --no-plugin option
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest --no-plugin block-1
npx @wordpress/create-block@latest --no-plugin block-2

# 5. Run build
cd [path-to]\my-plugin
npm run build
```

Update the `create_block_my_plugin_block_init()` function to register both blocks:

**my-plugin.php**

```php
function create_block_my_plugin_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/block-1' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/blocks/block-2' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_block_my_plugin_block_init' );
```

Test the plugin from the Editor to see both `block-1` and `block-2` load without error.

At this stage, you have a solid foundation for a basic plugin with two working blocks, properly compiled with their assets.

*The next steps are optional to extend the plugin with an Admin page.*

**2. Admin Page Setup**

The `src/admin/` directory will contain a `index.js` script which imports the `stylesheet/style.scss` as its required for build process. The `index.js` *does not load* any blocks.

**src/admin/index.js**

```js
import './stylesheet/style.scss';
...
// Other code for Admin Page..
```

**3. Build Setup**

Create a new custom `webpack.config.js` to enable additional entry points for your project to build all required assets:

**[my-plugin]/webpack.config.js**

```js
const defaultConfig = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        'admin/index': './src/admin/',
        'blocks/block-1/index': './src/blocks/block-1/',
        'blocks/block-2/index': './src/blocks/block-2/'
    },
};
```

**4. Updates to Main Plugin File**
Next, update `my-plugin.php` to include your original `class MY_PLUGIN` code with the following update to `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts()`:

**my-plugin.php**

```php
class MY_PLUGIN
{
...

    /**
     * Load admin scripts and stylesheets
     */
    public function load_custom_wp_admin_scripts($hook)
    {
        // Load only on ?page=my-plugin
        if ('toplevel_page_my-plugin' !== $hook) {
            return;
        }

        // Register and load admin script with dependancies
        $asset_file = include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'build/admin/index.asset.php';
        wp_register_script('my-plugin-admin', plugins_url('build/admin/index.js', __FILE__), $asset_file['dependencies'], $asset_file['version']);
        wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin-admin');

        // Register and load admin style.css.
        $admin_style = plugins_url('build/admin/style-index.css', __FILE__);
        wp_register_style('my-plugin-admin-style', $admin_style, array(), '1.0'); // check
        wp_enqueue_style('my-plugin-admin-style');
    }
...
}
```

Check that all the file paths are correct then rebuild your project. The build directory for each block now only contains that blocks assets; the script and style assets in for the Admin page are output to `build\admin\`.

[Example Project Directory Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTmQ0.png)

Now you can go on and create as many new blocks as you like!

**Additional Notes**
The errors shown in the updated question screenshot indicate that:

1. 'view.asset.php` is missing means that "view.js" is defined block.json but no "view.js" exists in your blocks directory or is a different filename.
2. The same as above applies to "editorSrc" where "index.js" is missing or the filename/path doesn't match.

Both are resolved by either adding the missing files or updating their declarations in `block.json` to correct path/filename for your project, eg:

```json
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "viewScript": "file:./view.js"
```

Ensure you rebuild the project and clear browser cache before testing again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. Just tried this and the blocks are working fine without any errors. But the issue is with admin page. It is not showing any components (an input field) and there's an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, which is coming from `admin/index.js` file. I have updated OP with the content of that index.js file. Please take a look. I think I have seen this issue before when I was trying to make it work.

Comment: No worries @s.khan - I've updated my answer to cover building the `admin/index.js` file with npm.  Most custom Admin pages are still primary PHP/frontend JS - unless you are [building your own block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/) as Admin page or a React app, hope this helps you..

Comment: Hey, now I am getting more errors in admin side and the blocks are missing. I have updated the OP with an ss of the errors.

Comment: Lol, mistakenly added the ss in your post. You can remove it.

Comment: And dont worry, I'll start a new bounty here.

Comment: Thanks @s.khan the errors in the screenshot are easily resolved - see bottom of updated the answer above. Also check in your main plugin file, the function `register_blocks()` is there and points to the correct path for the blocks relative to your project and it should all work...

Comment: Hey. If you meant adding the file paths in block.json that are in src folder, then they are currently pointed correctly. But if you meant pointing the paths to the files in build folder, then sadly that is not possible. After registering admin as you mentioned, all the files in `build/blocks/block-1` and `build/blocks/block-2` disappeared. Except it has only the blocks.json file. And admin dir in build folder consists of these three files: `index.asset.php`, `indes.js` and `index.js.map`.

Comment: Can you try it in your machine? I think this needs an expert to make it work.  Or may be we cant use React for admin side at all.

Comment: Try creating a new project again with the steps I gave, examine the default files and configs it creates, build it then extend it to add `/src/admin`. I suspect you still have a `index.js` file somewhere that is importing all assets in your current project -  the only 'index.js` files I have are in `/src/admin` and `/src/blocks/block-*` - no other is needed as the `register_blocks()` function loads the block assets from `block.json` and the `webpack.config.js` builds `admin/index.js`

Comment: @s.khan I also feel at this point this issue is a different problem from the original question and it would be best as a new question regarding project setup.

Comment: I created this new project and followed each and every steps you suggested. I also dont have any other index.js files apart from that in admin dir and blocks dir. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Hmm, in `webpack.config.js`, try adding the blocks to build as well: `entry: {'admin/index': './src/admin/','blocks/block-1/index': './src/blocks/block-1/','blocks/block-2/index': './src/blocks/block-2/'}`

Comment: I made some changes to that `load_custom_wp_admin_scripts` function. Your example was registering the script where you put the actual path of the admin dir. But it should be the build path. I also removed `view.js` as I don't think I need it. Both admin page and blocks are working except one thing. The admin page's stylesheet is not taking effect. There are no stylesheets in `build/admin`. Only three files: `index.asset.php`, `indes.js` and `index.js.map`.  Updated the OP with the new function.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and I commented in my code example as such "NB. Does not import blocks, just contains Admin page specific JS and is *not built by default*". The main goal of my example code was to show you the resolution for the "block is already registered" issue then it became build a complete project out which is really another issue.. Hope it's all working for you now..

Comment: I am grateful for the time you have provided, but I had a working project with admin and multiple blocks. The issue was with 'block is already registered'. You have provided a different solution and it broke my admin side. Isn't that supposed to work as well with your example? As you are saying that it is a complete different issue fixing anything other 'block is already registered' is not right. You gave me a solution and it is breaking other things. You're supposed to help me with that as well.

Comment: And I am not saying you haven't helped. You did. And I thank you for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254987/discussion-between-s-walsh-and-s-khan).

Answer (score 2):

How about checking if the block is already registered?

```
if ( ! WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->is_registered( $name ) ) {
    register_block_type( $name );
}
```

You can check the WordPress documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_block_type_registry/is_registered/).

For JS:

```
import { getBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

if (!getBlockType('foo/column')) {
    registerBlockType('foo/column', {
        edit: Edit,
        save,
    });
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-blocks/#getblocktype).

Comment: Hey, I tried this. And while this worked as well, I chose to go with S.Walsh's solution as I think that is a better approach in building multiple blocks and an admin page with React.